# c# WebBrowser Flash fullscreen - ESC won't exit fullscreen

Tags: c#, flash, browser

I have a swf inside a html page. If I open it with IE or FF and put it into full screen I can exit full screen with the ESC button.

Now if i try this with my WinForms app and WebBrowser (or ShockWave Flash Object) it's not working??

Any ideas?

Comment: may or may not be related, but silverlight has the same problem (http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/79333/187043.aspx). Other ActiveX containers such as MFC's CDialog or QT works fine with flash player, but wxPython and Java's SWT have the same problem with the flash player.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but Ctrl + W does the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

As outlined [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/csharpgeneral/thread/3a048d00-2dbd-4b07-a860-c09bd1e254e9) there is a problem with Windows Forms' ActiveX container support. The keyboard message does not get passed to the Flash player.

The solution I've come up with (based on code from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8f573d2c-7ba5-480e-a25d-b2ce608d8b5f/)) is to write a keyboard hook to catch the Escape key and to pass a message to the Flash window to close if it's active.

First, there's the `KeyHook` class which provides the plumbing to listen for the Escape key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Your.Utility
{
    public class KeyBordHook
    {
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        private const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

        //Global event 
        public event KeyEventHandler OnKeyDownEvent;
        public event KeyEventHandler OnKeyUpEvent;
        public event KeyPressEventHandler OnKeyPressEvent;

        private static int hKeyboardHook = 0;

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; //keyboard hook constant

        private HookProc KeyboardHookProcedure; // declare keyhook event type

        //declare keyhook struct 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class KeyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern int ToAscii(int uVirtKey, int uScanCode, byte[] lpbKeyState, byte[] lpwTransKey, int fuState);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] pbKeyState);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private delegate int HookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private List<Keys> preKeys = new List<Keys>();


        public KeyBordHook()
        {
            Start();
        }

        ~KeyBordHook()
        {
            Stop();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            //install keyboard hook 
            if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
            {
                KeyboardHookProcedure = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc);
                //hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProcedure, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
                Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule;

                hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProcedure, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);

                if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
                {
                    Stop();
                    throw new Exception("SetWindowsHookEx ist failed.");
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            bool retKeyboard = true;

            if (hKeyboardHook != 0)
            {
                retKeyboard = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
                hKeyboardHook = 0;
            }
            //if unhook failed 
            if (!(retKeyboard)) throw new Exception("UnhookWindowsHookEx failed.");
        }

        private int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {

            if ((nCode >= 0) && (OnKeyDownEvent != null || OnKeyUpEvent != null || OnKeyPressEvent != null))
            {
                KeyboardHookStruct MyKeyboardHookStruct = (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));

                if ((OnKeyDownEvent != null || OnKeyPressEvent != null) && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                {
                    Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;
                    if (IsCtrlAltShiftKeys(keyData) && preKeys.IndexOf(keyData) == -1)
                    {
                        preKeys.Add(keyData);
                    }
                }

                if (OnKeyDownEvent != null && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                {
                    Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;
                    KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(GetDownKeys(keyData));

                    OnKeyDownEvent(this, e);
                }

                if (OnKeyPressEvent != null && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    byte[] keyState = new byte[256];
                    GetKeyboardState(keyState);

                    byte[] inBuffer = new byte[2];
                    if (ToAscii(MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode,
                    MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode,
                    keyState,
                    inBuffer,
                    MyKeyboardHookStruct.flags) == 1)
                    {
                        KeyPressEventArgs e = new KeyPressEventArgs((char)inBuffer[0]);
                        OnKeyPressEvent(this, e);
                    }
                }

                if ((OnKeyDownEvent != null || OnKeyPressEvent != null) && (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP))
                {
                    Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;
                    if (IsCtrlAltShiftKeys(keyData))
                    {

                        for (int i = preKeys.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            if (preKeys[i] == keyData)
                            {
                                preKeys.RemoveAt(i);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (OnKeyUpEvent != null && (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP))
                {
                    Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;
                    KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(GetDownKeys(keyData));
                    OnKeyUpEvent(this, e);
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private Keys GetDownKeys(Keys key)
        {
            Keys rtnKey = Keys.None;
            foreach (Keys keyTemp in preKeys)
            {
                switch (keyTemp)
                {
                    case Keys.LControlKey:
                    case Keys.RControlKey:
                        rtnKey = rtnKey | Keys.Control;
                        break;
                    case Keys.LMenu:
                    case Keys.RMenu:
                        rtnKey = rtnKey | Keys.Alt;
                        break;
                    case Keys.LShiftKey:
                    case Keys.RShiftKey:
                        rtnKey = rtnKey | Keys.Shift;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            rtnKey = rtnKey | key;

            return rtnKey;
        }

        private Boolean IsCtrlAltShiftKeys(Keys key)
        {

            switch (key)
            {
                case Keys.LControlKey:
                case Keys.RControlKey:
                case Keys.LMenu:
                case Keys.RMenu:
                case Keys.LShiftKey:
                case Keys.RShiftKey:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you need to create an instance of the `KeyHook` class in your Windows Form ...

```
// inside Form class ...
private readonly KeyBordHook _keyBordHook = new KeyBordHook();

private void InitKeyHook()
{
    _keyBordHook.OnKeyPressEvent += new KeyPressEventHandler(_KeyBordHook_OnKeyPressEvent);
    _keyBordHook.Start();
}

void _KeyBordHook_OnKeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Escape))
        WindowHelper.CloseWindowIfActive("Flash");
}
public void StartKeyListening()
{
    InitKeyHook();
}

public void StopKeyListening()
{
    _keyBordHook.Stop();
}
```

And, the code to actually close the Flash Window...

```
public sealed class WindowHelper
{
    [DllImport("USER32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("USER32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("USER32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        bool returnValue = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (!returnValue)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        return true;
    }

    public static void CloseWindowIfActive(string windowTitle)
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, buff, nChars) <= 0) return;

        if (buff.ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(windowTitle.ToLower()) > -1)
            CloseWindow(handle);
    }       
}
```

I'm sure there's improvements to be made in all of the above but so far, this solution appears to work for me.

**Note** that this code allows you to *record all key strokes* across all apps so it's definitely overkill and may not be desirable to integrate into a customer bound application!

Comment: Don't forgot to call StartKeyListening() and StopKeyListening() ... probably on form open and close.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try F11? That's the default for IE.